# Why does my ViewController still reload every time I segue to it?

Tags: ios, swift

The header of my `HomeViewController` looks like this:

```
private let sharedGameBoard = HomeViewController()

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

class var sharedInstance: HomeViewController {

    return self.sharedInstance

}
```

I have my `HomeViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. To navigate to a `MultipleChoiceViewController` I call:

```
var multipleChoiceVC: MultipleChoiceViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("multipleChoiceViewController") as! MultipleChoiceViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(multipleChoiceVC, animated: true)
```

To return from `MultipleChoiceViewController` I call a `show` segue that is hooked up to a swipe gesture in my `main.storyboard` file.

Every time I navigate from `MultipleChoiceViewController` to `HomeViewController`, `HomeViewController` completely reloads. How do I keep this from happening. Like is seen in so many applications, I would like to be able to navigate from detail views back to the home controller without the home controller loading each time.

My load functions are called in `viewDidLoad` but I have a global bool variable that indicates whether the load functions should be called or not.

I've spent a good deal of time trying to understand singletons, push/show segues, and the navigation stack, to try and alleviate what is probably a very simple thing to accomplish. What is a way to implement this?

Comment: You shouldn't use a singleton for a view controller. For a singleton to work you need any object that needs a reference to call `sharedInstance` rather than the standard init function. `instantiateViewControllerWithIndentifier` is going to call `init(coder)` so you will have a new instance. Since you are in a UINavigationController you need to pop back to the home controller rather than pushing a new one; look into unwind segues

Comment: @Paulw11 My man. Yep, that was easy enough. Unwind segue did the trick. Thank you!